# Place form at center of page using bootstrap

Tags: css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal

I have a bootstrap login form appearing at the top centered page but i need it to present at the center of page.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3 well offset4">
      <div class="">
        <div class="text-warning">
          <h3>Login to our site</h3>
          <p>Enter your username and password to log in</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="">
        <form role="form" action="" method="post" class="">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="sr-only" for="form-username">Username</label>
            <input type="text" name="form-username" placeholder="Username..." class="form-control" id="form-username">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="sr-only" for="form-password">Password</label>
            <input type="password" name="form-password" placeholder="Password..." class="form-control" id="form-password">
          </div>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning col-sm-12"><strong>Sign in!</strong></button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

How can i center this form to a page using bootstrap/angularjs?

Comment: Have you tried applying some CSS properties?

Comment: i dont want to use any css . I have to use only bootstrap or angular

Comment: This isn't something built into bootstrap. You have to do it yourself with some CSS.

Comment: @ShashankG I think Poldria has right, you can't use just Bootstrap, that is css, to fix it, it's impossible

Comment: Oh ok ..thanks guys@Poldira@Teshtek

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default bootstrap has no tools to vertical centering.

For a login page you can just add this absolute centering :

```
  .perfect-centering {
     position: absolute;
     top: 50%;
     left:50%;
     transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
   }
```

Maybe it will be include as mixin in Bootstrap 4 ... But for now, you have to use additional styles,
I think.

Answer (score 1):

I added just a div outside yours container :

```
<div class="center">    
<div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3 well offset4">
                        <div class="">
                            <div class="text-warning">
                                <h3>Login to our site</h3>
                                <p>Enter your username and password to log in</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="">
                            <form role="form" action="" method="post" class="">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="sr-only" for="form-username">Username</label>
                                    <input type="text" name="form-username" placeholder="Username..." class="form-control" id="form-username">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="sr-only" for="form-password">Password</label>
                                    <input type="password" name="form-password" placeholder="Password..." class="form-control" id="form-password">
                                </div>
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning col-sm-12"><strong>Sign in!</strong></button>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
</div>
```

also a new css class defined as :

```
.center{
  position:absolute;
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
  padding:10px;
  -ms-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  }
```

UPDATE: if you have in local your bootstrap file just add this class without create other files, if you link to bootstrap tou can maybe add a div with style, like :

```
<div style=" position:absolute;
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
  padding:10px;
  -ms-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);">....</div>
```

instant of center class

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution without absolute positioning using view-height. It will probably retain the responsive width of the form.

CSS

```
/* body {height:100vh;} */ /* if needed */
.full-height {height:100vh;background-color:yellow;}/* 100% of the view-height */
.form-height {margin-top:-130px;}/* minus half the form-height */
.form-v-middle {margin-top:50vh;}/* half the view-height */
```

HTML

```
<div class="container full-height">
  <div class="row form-height">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3 well offset4 form-v-middle">
      <div class="">
        <div class="text-warning">
          <h3>Login to our site</h3>
          <p>Enter your username and password to log in</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="">
        <form role="form" action="" method="post" class="">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="sr-only" for="form-username">Username</label>
            <input type="text" name="form-username" placeholder="Username..." class="form-control" id="form-username">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="sr-only" for="form-password">Password</label>
            <input type="password" name="form-password" placeholder="Password..." class="form-control" id="form-password">
          </div>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning col-sm-12"><strong>Sign in!</strong></button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Example:
http://www.bootply.com/2wtIZimo3W

vh browser support:
http://caniuse.com/#search=vh